# Return value in all rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a case statement or other function that lets me return the value across multiple selected columns in a table? The names will always be the same if there is not a null in the other columns. There is not a case where all three name columns have a null.

What I have thought of so far is a case statement that goes through all 3 combinations of null and is not null, but is there an easier way?

Example:

| Name1 | Name2 | Name3 | Names |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| null | null | John | John |
| null | Jim | null | Jim |
| James | James | null | James |
| John | John | John | John |

Comment: `COALESCE(Name1, Name2, Name3) AS Names`

Comment: @HoneyBadger nice one, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `coalesce`

```
select COALESCE(Name1, Name2, Name3) AS Names
from table
```